# C# + MySQL - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I read every post I saw here and online about this subject, and still can't figure this out, because the problem I have is not with the reader itself but with the user "asking the program to use the reader a second time", I'll try to narrow the issue as best as I can. 
My program is able to properly connect, insert, update and read, but the problem is, when, without exiting the app the user tries to read again (which in the production environment will sure happen), then the program realizes that there's already an open DataReader associated with this Connection.

```
var candidateReader = daoMySql.GetMySqlDataReader(query); //a breakpoint on this line showed that the error is here, when it executes again
candidateReader.Read();
```

I'm actually closing the connection after using it, with

```
candidatoReader.Close();
```

But for some reason it seems that it isn't actually closing it(?)

How can I solve this? What am I not seeing here?

***EDIT:***

If I try to read using the same DataReader, after I close it, the error I get is

> Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed.

which makes sense, what I don't understand is why it gives the original error, but what I'm starting to realize is that the problem might be in the fact that the method is a static one, and is inside a static class, I'll try changing this so I can instantiate a class and use this method to see if the problem persists.

UPDATE: I tried what I explained in the previous edit and didn't work, this is what `GetMySQLDataReader(string query)` does

```
internal MySqlDataReader GetMySQLDataReader(string query)
{
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection);
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

The `Connection` that `GetMySQLDataReader` uses is always the same...

***Update:***

I found out where the error was, there was another method that returned `reader.HasRows` that didn't close that DataReader, fixed that, and now it works OK, so, long story short. If anyone else has this problem, please check that no other DataReaders are left opened.

Comment: Can you share more code which tries to use the same DataReader twice?

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya please check the last update, I just fixed it.